# Export to Excel and formatting cells using ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, spreadsheet, export-to-excel, coldfusion-10

I have a query which I'd like to output in a spreadsheet in Excel. I'd like some of the cell columns to be formatted in a certain way, which is thousands grouping and in Number format so that sums, additions etc can be done on that row without any further alteration.

I have read through the documentation but it has left me a bit confused on how to output to Excel in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I started out with a comment but it will be easier to read as an answer.*

What have you tried?  Have you read through the [CFSpreadsheet documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17cba-7f87.html)?  Should be pretty straight forward. One of the parameters to the `CFSpreadsheet` tag is 'query'.  Why not start with that and see how it formats the columns for you by default to see what needs tweaking.

Here is an example taken directly from the referenced documentation page:

```
<cfquery name="courses" datasource="cfdocexamples"> 
    SELECT CORNUMBER, DEPT_ID, COURSE_ID, CORNAME 
    FROM COURSELIST 
</cfquery> 

<cfscript> 
    //Use an absolute path for the files. ---> 
    theDir=GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()); 
    theFile=theDir & "courses.xls"; 
    //Create an empty ColdFusion spreadsheet object. ---> 
    theSheet = SpreadsheetNew("CourseData"); 
    //Populate the object with a query. ---> 
    SpreadsheetAddRows(theSheet,courses); 
</cfscript>

<!--- Write the sheet to a file ---> 
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#theFile#" name="theSheet" sheetname="courses" overwrite=true>
```

See the documentation for [SpreadsheetFormatColumn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6806.html), [SpreadsheetFormatColumns](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-677a.html), [SpreadsheetFormatRow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-676f.html) and [SpreadsheetFormatRows](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-676e.html) to read about formatting particular cells.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `cfspreadsheet` tag to create the file, and you can format the cells with the `spreadsheetFormat*` functions. You can find an example of how to do this at [Ray Camden's site](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/6/1/ColdFusion-Sample--Create-an-Excel-File).